# Add content type drop down menu to custom form

Tags: 2013, content-type, custom-form

I need to add a drop down list to a custom form that allows you to select the content type.  The default editform.apsx has this menu but when I create a new custom edit form I can not see how to add the menu nor can I see it in the editform.apsx to copy!